# How to center the floating element?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to center my menu which contains the ul menu.

The menu is float to the left and I can't seem to center the menu to the middle of the screen.

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <nav>
        <ul> 
            <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>item4</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>item5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
nav ul{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    font:bold .6em arial;
    float: left;
    margin: .3em;
    padding: 1.3em;
    background-color: #A8A8A8;
}

//the and margin text align doesn't seem to work...
section {
   text-align:center;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to provide a width.

Comment: Your code as posted appears to work fine when you remove the invalid comment syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/rMEZC/

Comment: @xec While you're correct, I'm pretty sure the OP only added that comment in here, to show where the problem area is, and it's not in the original CSS.

Comment: @MrLister My point is that without the comment - there is no problem (albeit the margin: auto does nothing, the menu is centered already)

Comment: @xec That's why I said you were correct ;)

Comment: Side note: using `section` around `nav` is likely wrong (unless you have other content in that `section`, too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KqaRT/1/)**

**CSS**

```
nav ul{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    font:bold .6em arial;
    float: left;
    margin: .3em;
    padding: 1.3em;
    background-color: #A8A8A8;
}

/*the and margin text align doesn't seem to work...*/
section {
   text-align:center;
   margin:0 auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by xec, the problem seems to be with the invalid comment syntax. The correct syntax for comments in CSS is `/*Comment Here */`. When the comment syntax is corrected, your code does center the menu.

```
/*the and margin text align doesn't seem to work...*/
section {
   text-align:center;
   margin:0 auto;
 }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/yZ4va/13/)

Answer (score 1):

You're not styling the `nav`. The `nav` inside the `section` is a block, and therefore it will be the full width of its container, whether you give the container `margin:0 auto` or not.

Solution: give the `nav` the same style as the `section`. Or, remove the `section` altogether, since it is not necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't particularly care about IE 7 and under (which have only partial support for `inline-block` - see http://caniuse.com/inline-block), this works, and has the advantage of making the links easier to hit: http://jsfiddle.net/V97tR/1/

```
nav
{
    text-align:center;
}

nav ul{
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
}
nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    font:bold .6em arial;
    margin: .3em;
    background-color: #A8A8A8;
}

nav ul li a
{
    display:block;
    padding: 1.3em;
}
```

Comment: @xec Ah, I should have known that. Thanks for the update. Will amend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box:

```
section {
   text-align:center;
   margin:0 auto;
   display: flex;
 }
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2c8LB/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSAuf/)

```
#wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
nav ul {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    text-align:center;
}
nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    font:bold .6em arial;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
    position:relative;
    right:50%;
}
nav ul li a {
    display:block;
    margin:0 0 0 1px;
    padding:3px 10px;
    background:#ddd;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:1.3em;
}
```