# Double unorder list center issue.

Tags: css, html

I have a question from my last post.

[How to center the floating element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267389/how-to-center-the-floating-element)

and I found out my problem is from the `<header>` tag before my `#menu tag`.

If I remove everything in the `header` tag, it seems I can center my item1 to item3 links.

However, if I add them back, my items menu will be a bit left instead of the center.

Here is my jsfiddle.

`//I want to center item 1 to item 3 links in my page..`.

http://jsfiddle.net/yZ4va/14/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you want to both of center?

Comment: no just second ul menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yZ4va/16/)**

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color: green;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    color: #000305;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;  
    color:white;
}

/* Headings */
h2 {font-size: 1.8em}   /* 22px */
h2 {font-size: 1.5em}   /* 22px */
h3 {font-size: 1.5em}   /* 20px */
h4 {font-size: 1.286em} /* 18px */

header#link{
   text-align:center;
   margin:0 auto;
}
header {
   margin:.8em;
    height:50px;
}

header ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}

header li{
    list-style: none;
    font:bold .6em arial;
    display:inline;
    margin: .3em;
    padding: 1.3em;
    background-color: #A8A8A8;
}
section#menu{
   text-align:center;
   margin:0 auto;
}

nav ul{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    font:bold .6em arial;
    float: left;
    margin: .3em;
    padding: 1.3em;
    background-color: #A8A8A8;
}
```